# Can I exit Dubai airport during a short layover?

Tags: indian-citizens, layovers, dubai, dxb

I am travelling to India from the US via Dubai on an Emirates flight. I have a seven-hour layover in Dubai. I have a brother who lives in Dubai.

Will it be possible for me to meet him in the airport lobby or some common place at the airport? Or do I need a visa? I am an Indian citizen.

Answer (score 4):

I was in the same situation couple of months ago. You will need a UAE visa because of the immigration holding transit area is out of bounds for people who are not travelling.

On the bright side, applying for a [96-hour UAE transit visa](http://www.emirates.com/uk/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/prearranged_uae_visas.aspx) is easy and quick from Emirates Airlines' *Manage Booking* portal if you are travelling with them. You don't even need to submit your passport for the visa if you are travelling with Emirates. I received a PDF bar-code visa in less than a day after applying.

If you are not travelling with Emirates, you should try the [traditional way of applying for a UAE visa](http://www.emirates.com/uk/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/visa-partners.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot exit the airport and your brother won't be able to pass the security check and meet you. You will need a visa to enter UAE.

Comment: This is a very low quality answer and needs proof, like links to and quotes from an official website. Unless done soon it will be deleted for lack on quality.

Comment: The answer may be low quality, but it is factually correct.